# Is it better to connect directly to an IP camera or stream the video through a server?

Tags: architecture, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

We have an IP camera, we have 100 people interested in watching the stream 12 hours per day.

If we allow people to connect directly to the camera then the bandwidth at that location is hammered, the IP camera has to be really top of the range and the video quality degrades.

If we stream the video through a server it seems as though the costs become astronomical, increasing per user.

What are the pros and cons and what's the best recommendations for designing this system in the most affordable way?

**UPDATE**: Currently all live streaming services I can find are using Unicast. With Unicast, each user gets their own stream meaning your bandwidth costs increase per user. This is incredibly expensive if you're streaming 24x7x365 (using e.g. Amazon CloudFront). (In my case we'd be streaming 12 hours per day, 5 days per week, all year round but still, the Unicast bandwidth costs make it unworkable)

What I need is a Multicast service that exists in the cloud but I cannot find one. Cisco seem to have bought a company that did what I'm looking for but now you need to call them to enquire, so I presume it costs an arm and a leg.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6552/products_ios_technology_home.html

Answer (score 1):

How would the cost increase per user?

In my opinion, it's better to stream the video with a server, for the following reasons:

### PROS

1. Most likely, the server will be LESS band-limited than the IP camera itself.
2. Scalability: the server will be better equipped to handle a larger number of load than the IP camera and presents the option of easily scaling your service as the request increases.
3. Overall QoS is better. And you're ready for the future anytime.
4. Cost is optimised. If you're hosting your service on the cloud - you pay for what you use. And what you get in return is reliability.
5. Definitely more flexible, you may want to develop other value added service on top of this - no one knows tomorrow.

### CONS

1. Appears to be more expensive - but really is it, if you care for quality?
2. Can't think of anymore disadvantages. Maybe administration cost? Don't know the whole picture...

### I'm writing here because the comment section will make it difficult to read:

So here we go...

I agree that PlanetStream is expensive. Streaming at the rate of 800kbps for 720 minutes (12 hours - 1 day) costs £250.00 - ridiculous!

For 100 viewers and with the parameters given above, what you get is 411.987 GB/day.

That amounts to £0.6068 per GB. Or $0.9811 per GB.

I strongly suggest that you have a look at [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)'s [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/): $0.120 per GB for the first First 10 TB / month. The rate gets cheaper even when you consume more.

**Finally, by my calculations (if I haven't made a mistake anywhere) you pay only £30.58 per day by Amazon CloudFront compared to Planet Stream's £250.00 per day.

Comment: re: How would the cost increase per user - that's really my key question for bandwidth costs - if we have 1000 users simultaneously viewing the stream does it cost 10 times more bandwidth than 100 simultaneous viewers?

Comment: This page here implies the costs increase per user: http://www.planetstream.net/prices/live-streaming-estimate.html

Comment: I have some cost estimations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901963/is-it-better-to-connect-directly-to-an-ip-camera-or-stream-the-video-through-a-s/13902163#13902163

Comment: I have edited my answer, giving a simple comparative cost analysis between PlanetStream and Amazon CloudFront. Amazon CloudFront is less expensive by a factor of 0.1223! The links to CloudFront and its pricing are in my newly edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help - It was originally Amazon Cloudfront I was looking at as this is the cheapest solution I can currently find but £30 per day is way too much for 100 users - the market we're building this for would pay £50 per year per person. If I can figure out a multicasting solution the whole thing becomes workable.

Comment: You can ease all this trouble by looking at video compression as part of the solution. There are lots of variables to consider you know. Hosting is just one of them. What format is the video? Can the size be reduced considerably by encoding it before transmission. Maybe you can consider skipping some (redundant) frames, and only request for skipped frames in critical cases (boils down to an optimisation problem). There are lot's of things to put into consideration altogether to help solve the problem. Hosting can't solve it all.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Wowza Media Server for IP camera restreaming but it was pretty expensive in the end (servers maintenance mainly). Now we use IP camera streaming providers like angelcam.com (but there are few others). The main advantage is that I don't care about IP camera compatibility anymore. We have many camera brands and it took ages sometimes to get some cameras to be working.

Comment: hwat you suggest Wowza is best or Angelcam is best??